# Mocking a generic method in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, mockito, overloading

I'm trying to write some test that involve [`JDKHttpClient` from ScribeJava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/blob/master/scribejava-core/src/main/java/com/github/scribejava/core/httpclient/jdk/JDKHttpClient.java) since i want to mock the OAuth service I'm using to do automated tests for my API.

Mocking the `execute` methods works fine:

```
val mockClient : HttpClient = mock(JDKHttpClient::class.java)
val responseBody = "{\"access_token\": \"gotit\", \"token_type\": \"type\", \"expires_in\": 3600}"
whenever(mockClient.execute(anyString(), anyMap(), eq(Verb.GET), anyString(), any(ByteArray::class.java)))
   .thenReturn(Response(302, "ciao", emptyMap(), responseBody))
```

When mocking only the `execute` methods I receive an NPE when trying to obtain the access token because the client tries to call the `executeAsync` variant. My problem is that I don't know how to mock those methods. The obvious thing to do is the following:

```
whenever(mockClient.executeAsync(anyString(), anyMap<String,String>(), eq(Verb.GET), anyString(),
    any(String::class.java),
    any(OAuthAsyncRequestCallback::class.java), 
    any(OAuthRequest.ResponseConverter::class.java))
).thenReturn(JDKHttpFuture(Response(302, "ciao", emptyMap(), responseBody)))
```

The problem is that the Kotlin compiler cannot infer the type `T` for the signature of these methods:

```
public <T> Future<T> executeAsync(String userAgent, Map<String, String> headers, Verb httpVerb, String completeUrl,
    byte[] bodyContents, 
    OAuthAsyncRequestCallback<T> callback, 
    OAuthRequest.ResponseConverter<T> converter)
```

How can I tell to the Kotlin compiler the correct `T` type?
Is there some syntax variation of:

```
any(OAuthRequest.ResponseConverter::class.java)
```

that allows me to set explititly the `T` type associated with `ResponseConverter`?

Comment: The current version of Mockito allows `any()` (without arguments) so you don't have to give a class argument at all.

Comment: @daniu That does not fix the issue. In fact from the IDE I see the number of errors *increase*. (It says:Type inferencer failed Not enough information to infer `T`).

Comment: looks like you're using kotlin-mockito there. Did you try to use its top-level `any()` function instead of Mockito's `any(Class)`?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 In both cases, using Mockito.any or kotlin-mockito's any, it says that there is not enough information to infer type `T`.

Comment: have your heard of [mockk](http://mockk.io)? It solves this problem easily

Comment: @Kerooker Right now I just wrote my custom mock class. When I have some time I will try to see if mockk can handle this can of overload+generic methods which don't seem to work with mockito or kotlin-mockito...

Answer (score 0):

Answering the original question:

> How can I tell the Kotlin compiler the correct T type for `executeAsyncMethod()`

You may give type parameters when you use the function.
For instance,

```
whenever(mockClient.executeAsync<String>(...
...
```